# map port number in url with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

**The Problem**

I would like to map a port number to the url of a site over a large range of ports.

That is if I have the following:

`mysite:30123` would become something like `mysite/30123`

For one case I can do this using nginx. I would like to do this for a large number of ports / a dynamic number of ports.

**Some Context**

I am using Docker Swarm to launch services, each time a service is launched it will be exposed to a random port in a range of ports, can I do this wthout writing a `location` for each port number?

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: I haven't had time to make a solution to this but I will be working on it soon. However it seems that there will need to be some kind of service that edits the config to achieve what I want here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this solution can help someone.

Nginx configurations:

```
map $request_uri $port {        
        ~^/your_path/(.*)$ $1;
        default '';
}

location /your_path {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port;
        }
```